# How to notify Polymer about changes to a field in a collection of objects

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Currently I have

```
@property List<DemoItem> demos = 
  [new DemoItem('a'), new DemoItem('b'), new DemoItem('c')];

...

@reflectable
void clickHandler([_, __]) {
  demos.firstWhere((d) => d.name == 'b').isActive = true);
  notifyPath('demos', demos);
}

...

class DemoItem extends JsProxy {
  @reflectable
  bool isActive = false;
  @reflectable
  final String name;
  @reflectable
  DemoElementItem(this.name);
}
```

**html**

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[demos]]" as="demo" >
  <paper-item active="[[demo.isActive]]">
    <div data-demo-name$="[[demo.name]]" 
      on-click="clickHandler">[[demo.name]]</div>
  </paper-item>
</template>
```

But the `active` state of the `<paper-item>` isn't updated, so this doesn't work and also doesn't seem very efficient. 
How to do this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to notify the exact path that changed, since the list itself is the same instance the notification is actually ignored otherwise. For example here is one option for the clickHandler, although not the most efficient:

```
@reflectable
void clickHandler([_, __]) {
  var demo = demos.firstWhere((d) => d.name == 'b')..isActive = true;
  notifyPath('demos.${demos.indexOf(demo)}.isActive', demo.isActive);
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I assume the efficiency-thingy is work-in-progress or planned for later?

Comment: Oh by not the most efficient I was just referring to how in the example I search the demos list twice. I could write a bit more verbose code (an actual for loop) and only search it once, but for examples sake I think this is the simplest to follow.